# How to convert random.choice into integer for experiment?

Tags: python, list, indexing, psychopy

I'm designing a psychophysics experiment using Python where I have auditory stimuli (syllables), text stimuli (pair) and a correct answer all stored in a csv file.

I am trying to make it so that the same text stimulus is not presented consecutively (eg. the auditory stimuli are 1, 2, 3, 4 & the text stimuli are did you hear "1" or "2" so I'm trying to avoid presenting this latter stimulus twice in a row).

I've created the following code:

```
Parameters_file = pd.read_csv('Parameters.csv', header=0)
Pair_list = Parameters_file['Pair']
syllable_list = Parameters_file['Stimulus']
corr_Ans_list = Parameters_file['corrAns']

past_syllable = [0] #To provide an initial auditory stimulus.

for i in range(len(syllable_list)):
     list_1 = [2,3,4,5]
     list_2 = [0,1,4,5]
     list_4 = [0,1,2,3]
     if past_syllable[-1] == 0:
          trial_index = randint(2,5,1)
     elif past_syllable[-1] == 1:
          trial_index = random.choice('list_1')
     elif past_syllable[-1] == 2:
          trial_index = random.choice('list_2')
     elif past_syllable[-1] == 3:
          trial_index = random.choice('list_2')
     else:
          trial_index = random.choice('list_3')
     past_syllable += str(trial_index)

  index = int(trial_index)
  Pair = Pair_list[index]
  corrAns = corr_Ans_list[index]
```

However, I keep getting the following error:

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 't'
```

Can anyone please help with this? Thank you!

Comment: `random.choice(list_1)` and so on

Comment: `random.choice('list_1')` should be `random.choice(list_1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
random.choice('list_2')
```

remove the quotes, because the above is simply a string, it returned "t" because it chose the 4th element in "list_2" which is t.